# Azure AD with HTML5 video

Tags: html, azure, html5-video, azure-active-directory

If I'm currently un-authenticated and try to load a video in the HTML5 video tag for a video that is protected by my Azure AD, it doesn't load the video.  I see that it tried calling /video/123 and returns a 302 with a location property of https://login.microsoftonline.com/...  It then makes another request for that location property and returns a 200.  The video is of course un-playable because it hasn't loaded the video asset.

Of course if I'm already authenticated, there's no issue.  How can I get the video to pop up the login screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your video is protected by AAD, and any requests against AAD require to contain the authorization header with access token. So, the unauthenticated request against to your video will be redirect to Azure AD SSO page.

The easiest and most direct way to achieve this, is to only accept the authenticated user to visit the special page with the video. To verify the user in the page, if they are not authorized, redirect to Azure AD SSO page.

You can leverage [adal for js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to implement the functionality with a ease. Meanwhile, you can refer to https://gist.github.com/Walk4Muscle/70b11b272131eedfc0360076fcd64b2c for the plain javascript integrating with ADAL for js.

Comment: Thanks Gary, that makes sense.  However, we still have the issue if they are authenticated on the page, then idle for 20 minutes or so, and then click on a video.  We have a list of videos and when one is clicked it changes the src attribute of the video element and starts playing it all with Javascript.  Any ideas on the idle issue when the next request that needs to be authenticated is a video in the video element?  Thanks!

Comment: You can leverage several third party js plugin to monitor the users' idle events. E.G. try to use https://github.com/kidh0/jquery.idle. When trigger `idle` event, redirect to login page, or refresh the access token.